# lowest possible timeuuid in php (phpcassa)

Tags: php, python, cassandra

pycassa has `pycassa.util.convert_time_to_uuid(time_arg, lowest_val=True, randomize=False)`

phpcassa has `static string uuid1 ([string $node = null], [int $time = null])`

Can phpcassa's uuid1 be used to get lowest/highest uuids like in pycassa?
If not, what's the best approach to ensure you get everything between two given timestamps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, Cassandra sorts primarily by the timestamp component of a v1 UUID, and in the case of a tie, it sorts by the remaining bytes:

```
int res = compareTimestampBytes(o1, o2);
if (res != 0)
    return res;
return o1.compareTo(o2);
```

phpcassa *should* offer something similar to pycassa here. As a workaround in the meantime, you can set the last 8 bytes of the return value to 0x00.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you have a column with a type of UUID version 1, Cassandra will ignore the 'unique' component of the UUID and just use the time part for the range.